# AlarmManager repeats endress

Tags: android

there is 3 classes.
service class,executing class, receiver class

fisrt, service class execute Amethod in "executing class"

the code in"executing class" is

```
Amethod(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("MY_ACTION");
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT );
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE );  
            am.cancel(pi);
            if(true){//to repaet every 10 sec.  
            am.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,10000, pi );
    }
}
```

this action will send to receiver.

```
if(action.equals("MY_ACTION")){
            Log.d("test","test");
            Amethod();
```

i suppose this "Amethod" will be called every 10 seconds.
but it repeats every 10 mill seconds,maybe method is called and called.

why this works so?
please tell me which code is my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a repeating alarm, don't set it every alarm like that.  Use setRepeating the first time, and it will continue thereafter.